# CakePHP 1.3: how to check if $this->save() is a success or fail?

Tags: php, cakephp-1.3

I revisited some old code I had written previously, where I have an if-else statement to check if a `$this->save()` is true or false for success or not. However, it seems that `save()` returns an array no matter what the input is and whether or not the data was saved in the database successfully.

Here is an example for a table named `product`, and it does NOT have columns named `iddd` or `out_of_stocksdsd`:

```
$temp = array();
$temp['Product']['iddd'] = '1';
$temp['Product']['out_of_stocksdsd'] = '1';           
$q = $this->save($temp);            
debug($q);
```

`debug($q)` returns what's below. Note that the array includes `modified` and `created` indices that are present in the table `product`.

```
Array
(
    [Product] => Array
    (
        [iddd] => 1
        [out_of_stocksdsd] => 1
        [modified] => 2013-02-07 21:28:51
        [created] => 2013-02-07 21:28:51
    )

)
```

The above does not update anything in the database, and, as you can see, there is no indication as to if it worked or not. So, how do I check whether `$this->save()` was successfully executed or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way I know how to check whether `$this->Model->save()` is successful or not is by using `if/else`. If the data is NOT saved successfully the only thing that is returned and should be in the variable `$q` is boolean `FALSE`.

Also, bear in mind that, CakePHP/PHP does not care what is in the array to be saved. If your Db table has 5 columns (id, name, content, created, modified), then cake will only care about those values(dependent on validations). If you add more columns to the array (idddddd, nameeeeee, anothercolum, etc), they will just be skipped and no error will be thrown.

The way the code is written here, it will never save anything because you are not passing an ID. Although the command will be successful, your entries will magically disappear once they reach MySQL. If you want to create new entries into the table you must call `$this->Model->create()` before you call `$this->Model->save()`, unless you are updating an entry in the table, which you will need to pass an ID or assign an ID as such: `$this->Model->id = 1;`

Comment: So, are you saying that `$this->save($q)` here will never return false, given that the array structure is correct according to CakePHP standards, no matter what the indices/values given(`iddd`, `nameeeee`) in `$q`? I did notice that if I pass in an `id`, it will update or create a new entry for that `id`, even if I pass in gibberish column names.

Comment: Correct. It does not matter what you pass there. It will only take what it needs, considering the ID is there if you are updating or you tell Cake to create one.

Comment: Do you know under what condition `$this->save()` returns false?

Comment: It only returns FALSE if it fails saving the data you want to save. If all your validations are fine, naturally save should work without a hitch. Something would have to be wrong with the DB for it to fail. Say, you want to save data[Post][view] as an Integer, but you have it setup a String in the Db, there is a chance it will fail. If you have a field that is REQUIRED and you are not passing anything and the DEFAULT is not set, it will fail.

Comment: Not applicable on CakePHP 2.x. Where you have checked it?